# How do I configure Drupal restws and format a create request

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-services

I have configured the path in the module:

```
function mymodule_restws_resource_info() {
    return array(
        'mymodule_person' => array(
            'label' => t('Person'),
            'class' => 'PersonResourceController',
            'menu_path' => 'api/person',
        ),
    );
}
```

That part seems to work, because when I send a POST transaction via Advanced Rest Client in chrome, I get a 200 response (I get a 404 if I change the request url).

That said, in the module I also throw an error if attempting an update, delete or read. When I send any of those, I still get a 200 response.

Any of GET, POST, PUT or UPDATE gives me

```
Response does not contain any data
```

including the create method in the resource controller, so it's not firing.

Do I need to do something to invoke it beyond hitting the url with a post payload?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to revolve around the workflow_moderation module being in the mix. If I enable restws and attempt just to hit node/1.json, I get a white screen and an error in the logs. It seems to be a known issue at this point that workflow_moderation is not including the correct parms when it passes the node on. [https://drupal.org/node/1238040](http://www.ecosia.org/url?url=https://drupal.org/node/1238040&v=2&i=0&q=drupal%20restws%20workflow%20moderation&p=0&tr=2670&at=0&ar=0&ab=0&mr=0&ir=0&kgr=0&nr=0&iar=0&sr=0)